# FATAL error ST-Link No MCU device found

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, stm32

I'am using IAR Workbench and I am having hard time to flash my STM32F407VG I got:

> FATAL error ST-Link No MCU device found.

- The USB cable connecting the laptop and the MCU is new so I don't think it's the problem.
- ST-Link en.stsw-link009 is installed

When I go to project options Debugger > ST-Link > Reset > connect during reset and try to download again I got:

> Warning stack pointer is setup to incorrect alignement stack `addr = 0x00000016` after the download progress bar stay blocked.

By navigating in the option menu I find it's possible to adjust CPU frequency actually it's 72 MHz, the default one, I changed it to 168 MHz, the CPU frequency but the problem remains.

Could you please suggest me some solutions to debug/resolve the problem.

**Edit**

I have used STM32 ST-Link Utility and i succeded to connect to the board, But the problem with my IDE is not resolved yet.

Comment: You forgot to mention what IDE you are using. Project options: Debugger does not tell a lot, what project. Guessing from the MCU you are using an STM32F4 Discovery board, or is it a custom board? To simply verify if you can connect to the chip I suggest to use [STM32 ST-Link Utlity](http://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stsw-link004.html).

Comment: @BenceKaulics Thank you for the feedback, i'am using IAR Workbench Yes i have used STM32 ST-Link Utility and i succeded to connect to the board. This is why i'am not sure to undrestand from where the problem come

Comment: Do you have a file called something like `stm32f407xx_flash.icf` in your project?

Comment: Yes i have this file in the project

Comment: Then first check your warning. There should be a line `define block CSTACK    with alignment =` . Now, I suppose it is equal 16 in your case. Is that correct?

Comment: I have an IAR EWARM project generated by [STM32CubeMX](http://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubemx.html) (I have never used IAR by the way) for an STM32F407VG (F4 Discovery) and it has the following line: `define block CSTACK    with alignment = 8, size = __ICFEDIT_size_cstack__   { };`.  And for the heap: `define block HEAP      with alignment = 8, size = __ICFEDIT_size_heap__     { };`.

Comment: Here is the whole file: http://pastebin.com/uMsYkWyD

Comment: [This is mine](http://pastebin.com/vzYeVmXe) it's also 8 in my case, by the way i have tried to download the image in a friend's board and it succeed so the problem is from the board itself but one may ask why it's connecting using ST-Link utility, does that mean that the bootloader is corrupted or smth like that, how  to know and how to correct ?

Comment: Note: You don't download, but upload. But even many (self-called) "experts" don't get this simple concept right.

Comment: @Olaf Actually Yes, but even in some IDE the operation is called "Download"

Comment: @Mouin: I think I wrote something about "experts" (mind the `\"`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used ST-Link Utility to erase flash memory, once this is done i activated

> Debugger > ST-Link > Reset > connect during reset

and all works well, i don't know why but i'am glad to see my board works again

Thank you for your help